# How do Swagger, Express/Nodejs, Sequelize fit all together in a App

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, swagger

I have some experience in Nodejs/Express, Sequelize and jwt apps. 
Recently I started looking at API Designing tools/Specs like RAML -- API Designer, Swagger -- Swagger Tools

I am wondering and I found no article linking or pointing out that how can I use swagger to create/design APIs and then use it in my nodejs/express app which uses Sequelize as an ORM.

JWT functionality is added on to middleware for authentication & authorization.

As I tested so far, I can export nodejs scaffolded app structure from Swagger-Editor using Server Code. On inspection, it actually routes the calls to swagger/YAML files.

How can I use sequelize alongside it?
Also, how do you guys go around from API Spec/Design to App (tools or workflow).

Please point where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the official documentation [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/). The docs might be written for v1.7.0 but I can tell you it's still relevant for usage in the latest Sequelize version (I have an actual server running with this design approach).

While your actual app's folder structure might be different due to Swagger's structure, but the way you use Sequelize within your app remains the same.